# Pontryagin dual of cokernel, $(\operatorname{coker} F)^* \cong \hat{H}^0(\operatorname{Gal}(L/K),E(L)), $

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-cohomology, poincare-duality

Let $L/K$ be a quadratic Galois extension of number fields. Let $E$ be an elliptic curve.

Consider the natural map
$$ F: H^1(\operatorname{Gal}(L/K), E(L)) \to \bigoplus_{v \in M_K} H^1(\operatorname{Gal}(L_w/K_v), E(L_{v_L})), $$
where $\operatorname{Gal}(L_w/K_v)$ denotes the local Galois group corresponding to the place $v$.

For an abelian group $M$, let $M^*$ denote its Pontryagin dual.

In this context, the Tate-cohomology group is represented as
$$ \hat{H}^0(\operatorname{Gal}(L/K),E(L)) = E(K)/(1+\sigma)E(L). $$(In other words, if we define a map $\operatorname{trace}:E(L)\to E(K), P\to P+P^\sigma$, it is $ \operatorname{coker}(\operatorname{trace})$.)

According to p214 of the cited paper ([link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02772219)), it's claimed that
$$ (\operatorname{coker} F)^* \cong \hat{H}^0(\operatorname{Gal}(L/K),E(L)), $$
but this is asserted without further explanation.

Could you provide some insights or suggest strategies for proving this isomorphism?

N.B.

The linked paper reads the dual of diagram $(3)$ on p 214 is the bottom diagram on p 214.
lem 5 on p 214 follows immediately if we confirm the titled isomorphism.

The notation used in this question is somewhat different from that of the paper. However, this question is still self-contained. I have provided a link to the paper for reference, but there is no mention of the isomorphism discussed in this question in the paper, even though it's described using slightly different notation.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which place on page 214 of that paper do you mean? It is all quite confusing for me since the Pontryagin dual in that paper is denoted by $(-)^*$ and there is no such thing on page 214; while there are lots of hats, and hat in that paper denotes profinite completion rather than Pontryagin dual as in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. I added the N.B. in the bottom of my question.

Comment: Is $L/K$ a quadratic extension? If not, then your definitions of the trace map and the Tate cohomology is wrong!

Comment: If you indeed want to get an answer, please write your question with more details. What is $E$?

Comment: Sorry, I added some information. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the relation between $L_w$ and $L_{v_L}$?

Comment: What is $F$? Is it related with $\mathcal F$ in the linked paper?

Comment: Lemma 4 on page 214 in the linked paper is indeed easy (though not obvious). If this is what you need, I can type a proof.

Comment: @Mikhail Borovoi Sorry, it is lemma 5. Lemma 4 has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: The notation used in this question is somewhat different from that of the paper. However, this question is still self-contained. I have provided a link to the paper for reference, but there is no mention of the isomorphism discussed in this question in the paper, even though it's described using slightly different notation.

Comment: What is ${coker} F^*$? Do you mean  $({\rm coker}\, F)^*$ of  ${\rm coker}( F^*)$ ?

Comment: I mean the former.

Comment: You nee a map. I will type it tomorrow.

Comment: I am very much looking forward to your suggestion. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\coker}{{\rm coker}}
$
I construct the required homomorphism.
Let $A$ be an abelian variety over a number field $K$, and let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension.
We denote by $A'$ the dual abelian variety.
Consider the following diagram with exact rows and columns:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
   0  @.                     0  \\
   @VVV                    @VVV   \\
H^1(L/K,A)  @>F>> \bigoplus_{v\in M_K} H^1(L_{v_L}/K_v,A)             \\
 @VVV                      @VVV                                       \\
H^1(K,A)  @>>> \bigoplus_{v\in M_K} H^1(K_v,A)@>>> \Big(\widehat{A'(K)}\Big)^*  @>>> 0  \\
   @VVV                      @VVV                        @VVV         \\
   H^1(L,A)  @>>> \bigoplus_{w\in M_L} H^1(L_w,A)@>>> \Big(\widehat{A'(L)}\Big)^*  @>>> 0
\end{CD}

Here the second and third rows are the exact sequences of the global duality theorem;
see, for instance, Milne, Arithmetic Duality Theorems, Remark I.6.14(b).

The first and second columns come from the restriction-inflation exact sequence;
see, for instance, Proposition 4 in Section 5 of
Atiyah and Wall, Cohomology of groups,
in: Cassels and Fröhlich (eds.), Algebraic Number Theory,  pages 94--115.

This diagram induces a homomorphism
$$ \coker(F) \to \ker\Big( \widehat{A'(K)}^* \to \widehat{A'(L)}^*\Big).$$
Dualizing, we obtain a homomorphism
$$\coker\Big( \widehat{A'(L)}\to \widehat{A'(K)}\Big)\,\longrightarrow\,(\coker\, F)^*.$$
Restricting, we obtain a homomorphism
$$\coker\Big( {A'(L)}\to {A'(K)}\Big)\,\longrightarrow\,(\coker\, F)^*.$$
I leave to OP to check whether this homomorphism is an isomorphism.

Comment: Let $f$ be the induced map 
$ker(\hat{A’(K)}^*\to \hat{A’(K)}^*$.
I believe that if I can prove $cokerF\to kerf$ is surjective, its dual is injective, and its restriction is also injective. However,  I am currently facing difficulty in proving that the induced map $ker(\hat{A’(K)}^*\to \hat{A’(K)}^*$ is surjective. Is it really surjective ? (If not, I have no tactics to prove injectivity of the last map)
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the formulas in your comment. Please re-type the comment.

Comment: You can click Edit under my answer, and then you can copy my LaTeX formulas. After that, don't forget to choose Cancel rather than Save edits.

Comment: $\newcommand{\coker}{{\rm coker}}
$ Sorry for confusion of my notation. I want to prove $\coker\Big( {A'(L)}\to {A'(K)}\Big)\,\longrightarrow\,(\coker\, F)^*$ is injective.  If I can prove $ \coker(F) \to \ker\Big( \widehat{A'(K)}^* \to \widehat{A'(L)}^*\Big)$ is surjective, then infectivity of $\coker\Big( {A'(L)}\to {A'(K)}\Big)\,\longrightarrow\,(\coker\, F)^*$ follows. But I  I'm stuck at the part of proving$ \coker(F) \to \ker\Big( \widehat{A'(K)}^* \to \widehat{A'(L)}^*\Big)$ is surjective.

Comment: Sorry, ×:infectivity $\to$ ○:injectivity.

Comment: Now, after you have retyped your comment, I see that I cannot help you.

Comment: Is this truly surjective as a matter of fact? If so, there's a possibility that it's rudimentary, so I'll reconsider it calmly once again.